# Button tooltip not getting localized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, tooltip

I have an extended button class as follows;

```
class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    private ToolTip _tooltip = new ToolTip();

    public ExtendedButton()
    {
        _tooltip.SetToolTip(this, StringResources.MyLocalizedTooltipString);
    }
}
```

In above code, 'StringResources.MyLocalizedTooltipString' contains strings for various languages. But when I change thread culture, tooltip text does not get changed. How to achieve that? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us how do you change the thread culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal. `SetToolTip` method accepts string and it will show the text that extracted from resource based on the current culture when calling `SetToolTip` and changing the culture at run-time will not have any impact on it. 
So here since setting tooltip is performed in constructor of your button, then the culture of thread at that moment will be used.

If you want your tooltip dynamically use the current culture automatially, as an option you can set a dummy text as tooltip (to enable the tooltip) and then handling `Popup` event of tooltip, assign the localized value to the tooltip:

```
class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    private ToolTip _tooltip = new ToolTip();

    public ExtendedButton()
    {
        _tooltip.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(_tooltip_Popup);
        _tooltip.SetToolTip(this, "DUMMYTEXT");
    }

    void _tooltip_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tooltip.GetToolTip(this) != StringResources.MyLocalizedTooltipString)
            _tooltip.SetToolTip(this, StringResources.MyLocalizedTooltipString);
    }
}
```

Note: If your goal is not making the tooltip dynamically localizable and you only want a localizable tooltip, the way `Localizable` property of `Form` works, go to designer of your `ExtendedButton` component and set `Localizable` property to `true` and then use different tooltip texts for different cltures.

But keep in mind, the value can not be changed dunamically at runtime, after the component is created.

Here is an example:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa-IR");
var f = new Form();
f.Controls.Add(new ExtendedButton());
f.Show();
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer. I've tested the codes and run-time dynamic localization works properly using those changes in the component. To test it's enough to have StringResources.resx and another one, for example StringResources.fa-IR.resx and show a form containing the button. Then change the `CurrentUICulture` at run-time and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

To comprehensively set the culture, you need to set the [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CurrentUICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx) for the current thread, and if you're going to create any new threads in your application, the [`DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture.aspx).

For example:

```
var frenchCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = frenchCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = frenchCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = frenchCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = frenchCulture;
```

This should be done in your program's `Main` method, before any forms are loaded and before [`Application.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx) is called.

From MSDN, regarding setting the default thread UI culture:

> Unless it is set explicitly, the value of the DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture property is null, and the current culture of all threads in an application domain that have not been assigned an explicit culture is defined by the default Windows system culture.

Comment: The tooltip value can not be changed dynamically at run-time, after the component is created. Becase the value is extracted at constructor based on the culture at the moment that the button created.

Comment: It doesn't need to be called in main method. It's enough to call it before showing a form. Then the form will use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` as it's ui culture. Also setting other properties than `CurrentUICulture` is point-less here.