# C# ToolTip Language changing during runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to localize a Tooltip during the runtime. All other Controls I change with this Class which works perfectly for Standard Controls and Toolstrip / Statusstrips :

```
public static class RuntimeLocalizer
{
    public static void ChangeCulture(Form frm, string cultureCode)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureCode);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType());

        ApplyResourceToControl(resources, frm, culture);
        resources.ApplyResources(frm, "$this", culture);
    }

    private static void ApplyResourceToControl(ComponentResourceManager res, Control control, CultureInfo lang)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(MenuStrip))  // See if this is a menuStrip
        {
            MenuStrip strip = (MenuStrip)control;

            ApplyResourceToToolStripItemCollection(strip.Items, res, lang);
        }

        if (control.GetType() == typeof(StatusStrip))  // See if this is a menuStrip
        {
            StatusStrip strip = (StatusStrip)control;

            ApplyResourceToStatusStripItemCollection(strip.Items, res, lang);
        }

        foreach (Control c in control.Controls) // Apply to all sub-controls
        {
            ApplyResourceToControl(res, c, lang);
            res.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, lang);
        }

        // Apply to self
        res.ApplyResources(control, control.Name, lang);
    }

    private static void ApplyResourceToToolStripItemCollection(ToolStripItemCollection col, ComponentResourceManager res, CultureInfo lang)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)     // Apply to all sub items
        {
            ToolStripItem item = (ToolStripMenuItem)col[i];

            if (item.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripMenuItem))
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem menuitem = (ToolStripMenuItem)item;
                ApplyResourceToToolStripItemCollection(menuitem.DropDownItems, res, lang);
            }

            res.ApplyResources(item, item.Name, lang);
        }
    }

    private static void ApplyResourceToStatusStripItemCollection(ToolStripItemCollection col, ComponentResourceManager res, CultureInfo lang)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)     // Apply to all sub items
        {
            ToolStripItem item = (ToolStripItem)col[i];

            if (item.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripMenuItem))
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem menuitem = (ToolStripMenuItem)item;
                ApplyResourceToToolStripItemCollection(menuitem.DropDownItems, res, lang);
            }

            res.ApplyResources(item, item.Name, lang);
        }
    }
}
```

But the Tooltip will not change. I added two languages into the Visual Designer. But language from Tooltip is always default.

I don't want to use a string table with Multilanguage support.

Comment: Is it WPF/WinForms?

Comment: Its "oldschool" Windows Forms

Comment: Here is an answer suggesting handling the tooltips pop event
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38353754/5916272